# How to get the Handle of a WindowsService in UserInteractive mode

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services, handle

I'm testing a third party hardware API which requires a `Handle` from my `Form` or `Service` to use it as its pipeline (*not my source code so don't blame me!*). I'm writing a windows service which consumes the API therefore I'm passing the `ServiceHandle` to it.

The thing is when I run the service in `UserInteractive` mode the `ServiceHandle` becomes zero.

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase

   if (Environment.UserInteractive)
       this.ServiceHandle; // equals zero
   else
       this.ServiceHandle; // a valid IntPtr
```

Should this be happening? Should I get the handle by another means? If so how do I do that?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.